# Using Globalize methods within ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, jquery-globalize

I want to use the the jquery-globalize **format** function within a **ng-bind** to format a date value in a **$scope** field according to the current culture.
Something like this:

```
<div>{{Globalize.format(test.testDate, Globalize.culture().calendar.patterns.d)}}</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

How do I accomplish this the easiest way?

Thank you

Comment: One solution to this would be to use that code in a controller and then use the controller variable within your html.

Comment: Don't I lose the two-way binding with this solution?

Comment: No. Any variable from a controller is bound to the scope where the controller is used. It's the nature of Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question mentions `ng-bind` but I don't see any use of it in your code. In any event, you can always use a controller to bind a variable to you views.

For example:

```
function HomeController() {
    var vm = this;
    // Any other variables here...
    vm.formattedDate = Globalize.format(test.testDate, Globalize.culture().calendar.patterns.d);
}
```

Then in your html you could do something like:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">
    <p>{{ homeCtrl.formattedDate }}</p>
</div>
```

Or if you are using something like ui-router, you could do:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        controller: 'HomeController as homeCtrl',
        template: '<p>{{ homeCtrl.formattedDate }}</p>' // Or use templateUrl.
    });
```

---

**Note:** If you are using `$scope` instead of the `this` method, it's basically the same process except you'll just trade the `vm.` syntax with `$scope.` and you can change `HomeController as homeCtrl` to just `HomeController`.